# How do I set a default value for a string?

Tags: php

I have a page that imports fields from a csv file and imports them into my database. Before the fields can be imported into my database I need to separate the name field into two separate values (first name & last name). I do it like so:

```
$name = $order[5];
$fname = sqlSafe(trim(substr($name, 0, strrpos($name, " "))));`
$lname = sqlSafe(trim(substr($name, strrpos($name, " "))));`
```

This seems to work reasonably well, but sometimes the name field has been left partially complete (they've entered just their first name or last name for example). This results $fname being blank and mysql won't allow me to set a default value for a BLOB/TEXT column.

To solve this I have tried a couple of `if` statements including:

```
if (!$fname) {$fname = "(blank)";}
if ($fname = "") {$fname = "(blank)";}
if ($fname = NULL) {$fname = "(blank)";}
```

None of which seem to catch it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you put the next part of the code where you save your data into the DB ? Maybe you're forgetting the quotes in the SQL statements.

Comment: `sqlSafe` is sounds a bit suspect, remember to [follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single `=` in your ifs will actually not test but assign a value. Use `==`or better `===` to test with if.

More info on test operators: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: So simple, I really am a bit rusty with PHP. Thanks for the quick response, I'm a go test this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the check immediately in the assignment:

```
$name = $order[5];
$fname = sqlSafe(trim(substr($name, 0, strrpos($name, " ")))) ?: '(blank)';
$lname = sqlSafe(trim(substr($name, strrpos($name, " ")))) ?: '(blank)';
```

Note the `?:`, that's the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) syntax.

Comment: Just tried this and (blank) never seems to get inputted. It is still leaving $fname blank for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use == instead of = to compare your string

Answer (score 0):

explode $name with `space`, and see the number of result.

```
$result = explode($name, ' ');
if (count($result) == 1) {
    $fname = $result[0];
    $lname = '';
} else {
    $fname = $result[0];
    $lname = $result[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that strrpos as well as substr might return FALSE instead of an int/string. You should check that first before decomposing $name.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
...

Having said that, explode is the function you are looking for. ;)
http://www.php.net/explode